# Invalid VirtualBox parameter "–cpuidset"

Tags: macos, cmd, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I want to add the OS X El Capitan to my Virtualbox on Windows 7. When I enter this code in the command prompt `VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "OS X El Capitan" –-cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff` the following error occurrs:

> [image: VirtualBox in Command Line]
>   At the very bottom, it displays the error: `VBoxManage.exe error: Invalid parameter ‘–cpuidset’`

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Make sure the two hypens(--) before the 'cpuidset'. The first one in your command line is not. They are litterally different in browser above. So, the command is invalid.

Answer (score 35):

Same thing happened to me after copying and pasting this line from a tutorial. If you look at your dashes, one of them is a long dash. they both need to be the short dash.

```
VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "OS X El Capitan" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff
```

should work!

Answer (score 5):

### I know this post is old, but in case anyone else is looking for info, here is the answer.

---

### Installing MacOS X on Windows with VirtualBox

The only problem I see is your `""`, you do not need that at the moment of call you **VM Name**. Additionally, try to give a name without spacing, it will be easier to call any **VM Name** without spacing.

Try it like this: (you may have to run CMD as an **admin**)

```
VBoxManage.exe modifyvm Lion --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff
```

On the above example **Lion** is my VM Name

After you have done with that you need to complete the setup with the following commands (**Lion** will be my **VM Name** for this example).

```
VBoxManage setextradata Lion "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3"

VBoxManage setextradata Lion "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"

VBoxManage setextradata Lion "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" "Iloveapple"

VBoxManage setextradata Lion "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey" "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"

VBoxManage setextradata Lion "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC" 1
```

And with that you can now start installing your MacOS X of your choose on VirtualBox (I have only tested with MacOSX Lion and MacOSX Sierra).

---

### Fix MacOS screen resolution after install the OS

After finish with the installation of MacOS X on your virtualBox you may found out that the screen resolution is not correct. To fix that issue do the following steps:

1. Close VirtualBox
2. Open CMD as an admin
3. Go to your VirtualBox folder

> cd C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox

4. Type the following command:

---

```
VBoxManage setextradata Lion VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution 1600x900
```

The "1600x900" screen resolution was just an example, here a list of resolutions to choose:

> 1280x720 | 1920x1080 | 2560x1440 | 2048x1080 | 3840x2160 | 5120x2880 |
> 1280x800 | 1280x1024 | 1440x900 | HD | FHD | QHD | 2K | 4K | 5K

Answer (score 1):

Run each line, one at a time.
This worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I approve this message